# SOLR boosting based on degree of match

Tags: solr, lucene

How can I boost a solr documents based for better matching documents on a certain field?

For example  I have a doc with something like `Assault M16`.

I  have 2 fields each indexing the text respectevely   `NormalText: assault m16` and `NormalTextNoSpaces: assaultm16`.

Now I search for  `Assault M 16 Gun` .
As a result I would get a bunch of documents contaning the words "assault", "m", "16", "Gun".

Thing is that I want to elevate all documents that perfectly match the  `NormalTextNoSpaces`  field, due to the fact  that it matches the search text better than the other filed.

This would be because the normal text field stores the text without having a space between the "M" and the "16". Therefore the match would not be so relevant as in the NoSpace filed.

What i want is some kind of function that tells me if the match if better on one filed or another so that I can boost document accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the (e)dismax query parser, you can give each field weight through the `qf` parameter: `q=Assault M 16 Gun&qf=NormalTextNoSpaces^100 NormalText` would give a match in `NormalTextNoSpaces` 100 times the weight than a match in `NormalText`.

The exact weight must be tuned for each use case and how you want to prioritize hits.

Comment: Thing is that I want to set the boost conditionally, so that when the match on normal text in less than the NoSpace match, it would give the NoSpace field a bigger boost/

Comment: You'll have to give examples, but that sounds like exactly what happens? Boosts aren't applied _unless there are matches_.